# How to make sure the layout of an activity no replace by other activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

Please help... 
I have
Activity 1 : consist of button for value, 5, 10,30,50, and 100.
Activity 2 : display the value that had been chosen in Activtity 1.

but.. what I get..
In Activity 2,the value not display..but, it display the value only when I use back button go to Activity1 and it using layout of Activity 2.

---

Activity 1

```
 public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
 public void onClick(View view) {


 switch (view.getId()) {

             case R.id.imageView2:


                  Intent intent7 = new Intent(IntentExampleActivity.this,more.class);
                  intent7.putExtra("YourKeyName", "RM 5");
                  startActivity(intent7);

                  break;

             case R.id.imageView6:
                  Intent intent2 = new Intent(IntentExampleActivity.this,more.class);
                  intent2.putExtra("YourKeyName", "RM 10");
                  startActivity(intent2);

                  break;

             case R.id.imageView3:
                  Intent intent4 = new Intent(IntentExampleActivity.this,more.class);
                  intent4.putExtra("YourKeyName", "RM 30");
                  startActivity(intent4);

                  break;

             case R.id.imageView02:
                  Intent intent3 =new Intent(IntentExampleActivity.this,more.class);
                  intent3.putExtra("YourKeyName", "RM 50");
                  startActivity(intent3);

                  break;

             case R.id.imageView06:
                  Intent intent5 = new Intent(IntentExampleActivity.this,more.class);
                  intent5.putExtra("YourKeyName", "RM 100");
                  startActivity(intent5);

                  break;

             default:

       };
```

---

Activity 2

```
    package com.prgguru.android;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;

 public class more extends Activity  {

TextView text1;
TextView text2;
Button btn1;
Button btn2;
String value;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.more);

    btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String valueFromIntent = intent.getStringExtra("YourKeyName");
      text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      text1.setText(valueFromIntent);

  }


public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {

public void onClick(View view) {


if(view.getId()==R.id.button1){
     Intent intObj = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                IntentExampleActivity.class);
            startActivity(intObj);

}

else if ((view.getId()==R.id.button2)){
     Intent intObj = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                reconfirm.class);
            startActivity(intObj);
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

I guess sending the Intent activity was wrong, but can't find the solution.For few days thinking about this problem. I'm newbie,help me please ~

Comment: post the whole Activity 2 code.

Comment: @user3714182 click the `btn2` and see result.

Comment: it will go to activity 3

Comment: @user3714182 if you are facing problem in passing the values i have posted an answer that might help you.

Answer (score -2):

**it display the value only when I use back button go to Activity1 and it using layout of Activity 2**

because you're putting the logic of setting the text values inside an onClickListener. Just do this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String valueFromIntent = intent.getStringExtra("YourKeyName");
text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
text1.setText(valueFromIntent);
```

inside your Activity 2's onCreate, outside of any onClickListener brace. It should work.